# get web page content using php script and save it in my db

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-get-contents, php-5.6

I want to get the content of this 1st and 2nd webpage https://www.goodreads.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9&search_type=books
and then store it in my database and then make the list is searchable.so after I googled I found that I can do it like this

```
$url = "https://www.goodreads.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9&search_type=books";

function get_links($url){

$input = file_get_contents($url);
echo $input;
}


get_links($url);
```

my problem is how can I get the 2nd page content also and how can I store these books in my database to the list searchable

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not that easy...

## Options

### Getting the pages (Not recommended)

To get a later page you can send the "page argument" in your request:
e.g.:
https://www.goodreads.com/search?page=2&q=%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9&search_type=books&tab=books&utf8=%E2%9C%93

But to get the Elements into a nice structure you need to parse the HTML you get which is realy hard.

### Use the API (recommended)

At https://www.goodreads.com/api/index you can find the documentation for goodreads API which returns example as response and is easily parseable.

### Parse XML in PHP

If you use the API you can parse the XML-response with SimpleXML.
See example 1 & 2: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

## Saving to database

If you are a beginner you might read some tutorials about how to use mysql with php and PDO. But you may also have a look at RedBeanPHP which is an really easy to use ORM for databases.

Answer (score 0):

For getting 2nd page you will have to append on the url `?page=2`

In case that you need to get other pages, you can use a `for loop` if you don't know how to use for loop, please google `php for loop`

For the database, google `php mysql insert`

Comment: Actually I know how to use mysqli and PDO but this my first time to deal with task like this I am trying to see the easiest way to do it so if you have another answer I would like to see it

Comment: @nebulak and I already answered the question. I guess you want an answer, so you just copy and paste it. Pretty much you are asking someone to do your work/homework for free. Got it! In that case, no, I don't have another answer. And btw, please read SO best practices on how to ask. You might not compliance with some the rules.

Comment: By another answer l meant tutorial that explain it or links should I look at it or topics should I google thats it.

Comment: Please read again @nebulak 's answer. He is telling you what to do and what you need to read. Or you can search API with php and than you have to read goodreads API documentation (pretty good documentation)